# Как реализовать смену картинок с переворотом?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Мне нужно реализовать бесконечную смену картинок, но чтобы при смене они переворачивались, как это лучше сделать? То что сейчас у меня есть работает не совсем правильно. Что мне нужно изменить в моем коде. Только начал изучать анимацию

JS
Сделал слайдер чтобы картинки менялись через 5 сек

```
    const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState<number>(0);

    const img = [
        <img key={orden1} src={orden1} />,
        <img key={orden2} src={orden2} />,
        <img key={orden3} src={orden3} />,
        <img key={orden4} src={orden4} />,
        <img key={orden5} src={orden5} />,
        <img key={orden6} src={orden6} />,
        <img key={orden7} src={orden7} />
    ]

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            setActiveIndex((current) => {
                const res = current === img.length - 1 ? 0 : current + 1
                return res
            })
        }, 5000)
        return () => clearInterval(interval)
    }, [])

    // Вычисляем индекс следующего слайда
    const nextImgIndex = activeIndex === img.length - 1 ? 0 : activeIndex + 1
```

HTML
У меня есть карточка с картинками с двух сторон

```
            <div className={s.slider}>
                <div className={s.sliderImg} key={activeIndex}>
                    <div className={s.front}>{img[activeIndex]}</div>
                    <div className={s.back}>{img[nextImgIndex]}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS
Картинки переворачиваются но это работает не правильно

```
.slider {
    position: absolute;
    top: 348px;
    left: 776px;
    width: 395px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    perspective: 1000;
}
 
.sliderImg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.slider:hover .sliderImg {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.sliderImg img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.front {
    z-index: 2;
}
 
.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если хочется что-то повращать бесконечно, на автомате, без hover, то можно попробовать что-то такое:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Слайдер</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        background-color: gray;
      }
      .stage1, .stage2, .stage3 {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        margin: auto;
      }
      @keyframes spincube1 {
        from,to {
          transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
        }
        16% {
          transform: rotateY(-90deg);
        }
        33% {
          transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg);
        }
        50% {
          transform: rotateY(-180deg) rotateZ(90deg);
        }
        66% {
          transform: rotateY(-270deg) rotateX(90deg);
        }
        83% {
          transform: rotateX(90deg);
        }
      }
      .cubespinner1 {
        animation: spincube1 ease-in-out infinite 10s;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transform-origin: 60px 60px 0;
      }
      .cubespinner1 div {
        position: absolute;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
      .cubespinner1 .face1 {
        transform: translateZ(60px);
      }
      .cubespinner1 .face2 {
        transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(60px);
      }
      .cubespinner1 .face3 {
        transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(60px);
      }
      .cubespinner1 .face4 {
        transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(60px);
      }
      .cubespinner1 .face5 {
        transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(60px);
      }
      .cubespinner1 .face6 {
        transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(60px);
      }
      @keyframes spincube2 {
        from,to {
          transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
        }
        16% {
          transform: rotateY(-90deg);
        }
        33% {
          transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg);
        }
        50% {
          transform: rotateY(-180deg) rotateZ(90deg);
        }
        66% {
          transform: rotateY(-270deg) rotateX(90deg);
        }
        83% {
          transform: rotateX(90deg);
        }
      }
      .cubespinner2 {
        animation: spincube2 ease-in-out infinite 10s;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transform-origin: 60px 60px 0;
      }
      .cubespinner2 div {
        position: absolute;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
      .cubespinner2 .face1 {
        transform: translateZ(60px);
      }
      .cubespinner2 .face2 {
        transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(60px);
      }
      .cubespinner2 .face3 {
        transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(60px);
      }
      .cubespinner2 .face4 {
        transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(60px);
      }
      .cubespinner2 .face5 {
        transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(60px);
      }
      .cubespinner2 .face6 {
        transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(60px);
      }
      @keyframes spincube3 {
        from,to {
          transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
        }
        16% {
          transform: rotateY(-90deg);
        }
        33% {
          transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg);
        }
        50% {
          transform: rotateY(-180deg) rotateZ(90deg);
        }
        66% {
          transform: rotateY(-270deg) rotateX(90deg);
        }
        83% {
          transform: rotateX(90deg);
        }
      }
      .cubespinner3 {
        animation: spincube3 ease-in-out infinite 10s;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transform-origin: 60px 60px 0;
      }
      .cubespinner3 div {
        position: absolute;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
      .cubespinner3 .face1 {
        transform: translateZ(60px);
      }
      .cubespinner3 .face2 {
        transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(60px);
      }
      .cubespinner3 .face3 {
        transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(60px);
      }
      .cubespinner3 .face4 {
        transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(60px);
      }
      .cubespinner3 .face5 {
        transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(60px);
      }
      .cubespinner3 .face6 {
        transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(60px);
      }
      .carousel-inner {
        text-align: center;
      }
      .container {
        background-color: violet; 
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div class="stage1">
        <div class="cubespinner1">
        <div class="face1"><img src="https://img0.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/d/3/159/312/159312496_preview_RyoRRRSRRRRRyoR_20230128_213651055.png" alt="winter"></div>
        <div class="face2"><img src="https://images.apksecure.com/logos/com.jwwallpapers.animehdscreenwalls_150x150.png" alt="summer"></div>
        <div class="face3"><img src="https://img0.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/d/3/159/312/159312496_preview_RyoRRRSRRRRRyoR_20230128_213651055.png" alt="winter"></div>
        <div class="face4"><img src="https://images.apksecure.com/logos/com.jwwallpapers.animehdscreenwalls_150x150.png" alt="summer"></div>
        <div class="face5"><img src="https://img0.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/d/3/159/312/159312496_preview_RyoRRRSRRRRRyoR_20230128_213651055.png" alt="winter"></div>
        <div class="face6"><img src="https://images.apksecure.com/logos/com.jwwallpapers.animehdscreenwalls_150x150.png" alt="summer"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="stage2">
        <div class="cubespinner2">
          <div class="face1"><img src="https://img0.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/d/3/159/312/159312496_preview_RyoRRRSRRRRRyoR_20230128_213651055.png" alt="winter"></div>
        <div class="face2"><img src="https://images.apksecure.com/logos/com.jwwallpapers.animehdscreenwalls_150x150.png" alt="summer"></div>
        <div class="face3"><img src="https://img0.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/d/3/159/312/159312496_preview_RyoRRRSRRRRRyoR_20230128_213651055.png" alt="winter"></div>
        <div class="face4"><img src="https://images.apksecure.com/logos/com.jwwallpapers.animehdscreenwalls_150x150.png" alt="summer"></div>
        <div class="face5"><img src="https://img0.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/d/3/159/312/159312496_preview_RyoRRRSRRRRRyoR_20230128_213651055.png" alt="winter"></div>
        <div class="face6"><img src="https://images.apksecure.com/logos/com.jwwallpapers.animehdscreenwalls_150x150.png" alt="summer"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="stage3">
        <div class="cubespinner3">
          <div class="face1"><img src="https://img0.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/d/3/159/312/159312496_preview_RyoRRRSRRRRRyoR_20230128_213651055.png" alt="winter"></div>
        <div class="face2"><img src="https://images.apksecure.com/logos/com.jwwallpapers.animehdscreenwalls_150x150.png" alt="summer"></div>
        <div class="face3"><img src="https://img0.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/d/3/159/312/159312496_preview_RyoRRRSRRRRRyoR_20230128_213651055.png" alt="winter"></div>
        <div class="face4"><img src="https://images.apksecure.com/logos/com.jwwallpapers.animehdscreenwalls_150x150.png" alt="summer"></div>
        <div class="face5"><img src="https://img0.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/d/3/159/312/159312496_preview_RyoRRRSRRRRRyoR_20230128_213651055.png" alt="winter"></div>
        <div class="face6"><img src="https://images.apksecure.com/logos/com.jwwallpapers.animehdscreenwalls_150x150.png" alt="summer"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете попробовать сделать следующее:

```js
const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState<number>(0);

const images = [
  { src: orden1, frontVisible: true },
  { src: orden2, frontVisible: true },
  { src: orden3, frontVisible: true },
  { src: orden4, frontVisible: true },
  { src: orden5, frontVisible: true },
  { src: orden6, frontVisible: true },
  { src: orden7, frontVisible: true },
];
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    setActiveIndex((current) => {
      const res = current === images.length - 1 ? 0 : current + 1;
      return res;
    });
  }, 5000);
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);

// Вычисляем индекс следующего слайда
const nextImgIndex = activeIndex === images.length - 1 ? 0 : activeIndex + 1;

// Переворачиваем картинку при смене слайда
images[activeIndex].frontVisible = false;
images[nextImgIndex].frontVisible = true;
```

```css
.slider {
    position: absolute;
    top: 348px;
    left: 776px;
    width: 395px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    perspective: 1000;
}
 
.sliderImg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.slider:hover .sliderImg {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.sliderImg img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.front {
    z-index: 2;
}
 
.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div className={s.slider}>
  <div className={s.sliderImg} key={activeIndex}>
    <div className={`${s.front} ${images[activeIndex].frontVisible ? '' : s.back}`}>
      <img src={images[activeIndex].src} alt="Front" />
    </div>
    <div className={`${s.back} ${images[nextImgIndex].frontVisible ? '' : s.front}`}>
      <img src={images[nextImgIndex].src} alt="Back" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```